# How to add text in an overlay in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

here is what i have tried to add "processing" as text in the middle of the window
on overlay

```js
function on() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}

function off() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<div id="overlay" onclick="off()"></div>

<div style="padding:20px">
  <h2>Overlay</h2>
  <p>Add an overlay effect to the page content (100% width and height with a black background color with 50% opacity).</p>
  <button onclick="on()">Turn on overlay effect</button>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Is their any way to add "processing" text to overlay  ?
I am trying that "processing" to appear in middle also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use and **easiest** way is to use [after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) CSS *pseudo-element* to add the word processing. This way it will be `responsive` on the *modern browsers* as well.

**Live Demo:**

```js
function on() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}

function off() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#overlay::after {
  content: 'Processing...';
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>

  <div id="overlay" onclick="off()"></div>

  <div style="padding:20px">
    <h2>Overlay</h2>
    <p>Add an overlay effect to the page content (100% width and height with a black background color with 50% opacity).</p>
    <button onclick="on()">Turn on overlay effect</button>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello, the text is not properly in the middle of the page.

Comment: @newphpdev It is in center - you need to click on run snippet and click `full page` to view it in the center.

Comment: Thanks, it looks good just missing responsive properties.

Comment: @newphpdev What do you mean by responsive properties ? it will be responsive on a an actual browser and will work on 
normally

Comment: Sir, i am talking about the text should appear as in center of the page from left right top bottom that would be great.

Comment: @newphpdev You can use my code and run on your own browser and then resize the browser the text processing... will resize automatically! That means responsive! It will always stay in the center sir.

Comment: Thankyou, what if the text gets increased from "processing" to "Please wait, while we are order processing your order " ? i am concerned about that.

Comment: @newphpdev Do not worry - it will always be responsive and will stay in the middle. If the text is getting tooooo bigger then you can set your own left and top. So make it more responsive as you like to.

Comment: Awesome, but it just text does not shrink with window resize. Alright thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simply place i.e. a `h1` in the `<div id="overlay" onclick="off()">`. It'll be hidden with it and only show when you open the overlay with JavaScript.

The CSS in the snippet at `#overlay h1` is just to center the h1 to the page.

```js
function on() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}

function off() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}

#overlay h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>

  <div id="overlay" onclick="off()">
    <h1>Processing</h1> <!--Add your text here -->
  </div>

  <div style="padding:20px">
    <h2>Overlay</h2>
    <p>Add an overlay effect to the page content (100% width and height with a black background color with 50% opacity).</p>
    <button onclick="on()">Turn on overlay effect</button>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello, the text is not properly in the middle of the page.

Comment: @newphpdev That was my fault, it was due to the "comment" in the CSS that the position style wasn't added, fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can add text in the overlay & use transform properties

```js
function on() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}

function off() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.txt {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  transform: translate(40%, 150px);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>

  <div id="overlay" onclick="off()">
    <div class='txt'>Processing</div>
  </div>

  <div style="padding:20px">
    <h2>Overlay</h2>
    <p>Add an overlay effect to the page content (100% width and height with a black background color with 50% opacity).</p>
    <button onclick="on()">Turn on overlay effect</button>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello, the text is not properly in the middle of the page.

Comment: not so responsive though. not in the middle of overlay